# Simple DOM file_get_html returns empty page

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with passing a complex url to file_get_html When I try this code

```
<?php

require_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/dom/simple_html_dom.php");
$base = $_GET['url'];
//file_get_contents() reads remote webpage content
    $html_base = file_get_html("http://www.realestateinvestar.com.au/ME2/dirmod.asp?sid=1A0FFDB3E8CD48909120C118D03F6016&nm=&type=news&mod=News&mid=9A02E3B96F2A415ABC72CB5F516B4C10&tier=3&nid=C67A9DD2C0144B9EB41DB58365C05927");

foreach($html_base->find('p') as $td) {
 echo $td;
}

?>
```

It works

But if I try to pass the url as a variable via `mysite.com/goget.php?url=http://www.realestateinvestar.com.au/ME2/dirmod.asp?sid=1A0FFDB3E8CD48909120C118D03F6016&nm=&type=news&mod=News&mid=9A02E3B96F2A415ABC72CB5F516B4C10&tier=3&nid=C67A9DD2C0144B9EB41DB58365C05927`

```
<?php

require_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/dom/simple_html_dom.php");
$base = $_GET['url'];
//file_get_contents() reads remote webpage content
    $html_base = file_get_html($base);

foreach($html_base->find('p') as $td) {
 echo $td;
}

?>
```

It returns a blank page.

Any help?

Comment: Does `require_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/dom/simple_html_dom.php");` even work as you expect? I would try `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/dom/simple_html_dom.php");`

Comment: no that's not the problem, the first section of code works with require_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/dom/simple_html_dom.php");, the second section of code doesn't

Comment: Try [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) your `$base` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php):

```
"mysite.com/goget.php?url="
.urlencode("http://www.realestateinvestar.com.au/ME2/dirmod.asp?sid=1A0FFDB3E8CD48909120C118D03F6016&nm=&type=news&mod=News&mid=9A02E3B96F2A415ABC72CB5F516B4C10&tier=3&nid=C67A9DD2C0144B9EB41DB58365C05927")
```